# POST route calls another POST route. Is it possible to get the 'res' of the second POST? express node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, axios

So I have a POST route that calls a function:

```
router.route('/generateSeed').post(function(req,res){
generate_seed(res)
});
```

**UPDATE:** Here is the **genrate_seed() function**

```
 function generate_seed(res)
{

    var new_seed = lightwallet.keystore.generateRandomSeed();
    generate_addresses(new_seed, res);
}

var totalAddresses = 0;

function generate_addresses(seed, res)
{
    if(seed == undefined)
    {
            console.log("seed")
    }
    var password = Math.random().toString();

    lightwallet.keystore.createVault({
        password: password,
        seedPhrase: seed,
            hdPathString: "m/44'/60'/0'/0" //added this changing from Default m/0'/0'/0'/

    }, function (err, ks) {
        ks.keyFromPassword(password, function (err, pwDerivedKey) {
            if(err)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                ks.generateNewAddress(pwDerivedKey, totalAddresses);
                var addresses = ks.getAddresses()
                var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://mainnet.infura.io"));//changed to infura as a provider
                var html = "";
                    var address = addresses;
                    var seedPhrase = seed;
                    addToAPI(address,seedPhrase, res); //address
            }
        });
    });
}

        function addToAPI(address, seedPhrase, res){
            var NewUser = {
         publicK: address,
                 seed: seedPhrase
             }

      axios.post('http://localhost:3000/CryptoWallet/add/createCryptoWallet', NewUser)//changed from localhost
    .then((res)=>{
       console.log("Response");
    })
      .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
```

Which calls to this **second route**:

```
router.route('/add/createCryptoWallet').post(function(req,res){

  var crypto_wallet = new CryptoWallet(req.body)
    console.log("The cyrptoWallet on create", crypto_wallet);
      crypto_wallet.save()
      .then(crypto_wallet =>{
        res.json({data: CryptoWallet({_id:1})}); //<<--- I want this line
      })
      .catch(err => {
        res.status(400).send("unable to save CryptoWallet to databse");
      });
});
```

**UPDATE** I do get it to POST and save in the database. Right now I can only get the response from the **first POST route** is there a way to get the response from the **second POST route** my final goal is the get the `_id` created by mongo as a response.

Thanks ahead!

Comment: Can you please add a snippet which shows how `addToAPI()` is called and where you call `next()`?

Comment: Hey @Volodymyr I just updated my question with the extra info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing response sending for your first **POST** request (`/generateSeed`). `addToAPI` function need to wait until second **POST** request is finished and the send its own response. So basically it should look similar to this:

```
function addToAPI(address, seedPhrase, res){
  var NewUser = {
    publicK: address,
    seed: seedPhrase
  }

  axios.post('http://localhost:3000/CryptoWallet/add/createCryptoWallet', NewUser)
    .then((response)=>{
       res.json(response.data); // axios wrappes the body of response into `data` object 
    })
    .catch(error=>{
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).('Some error occured');
    })
}
```